# Como verificar paginação no selenium webdrive - java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Olá,

Estou com dificuldade de como verificar a quantidade de linhas, para verificar se pode ou não realizar uma paginação.

Estou utilizando - selenium webdriver - java

Obrigada.

Comment: Você já tem algum código? Sua pergunta está muito genérica. (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Bem vinda ao StackOverflow em Português, talvez queira fazer uma **Tour**: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour ou dar uma olhada na **Central de Ajuda**: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help e verificar como efetuar perguntas de uma forma que sejam respondidas rapidamente, tente informar o que você já tentou e poste o seu código, dificilmente alguém fará o trabalho por você.